# D3 ordinal scale adding numbers to the end

Tags: d3.js

I am creating an ordinal scale like so:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"])
          .rangeBands([0, width], .1);
```

If I use this scale with an axis:

```
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .call(xaxis)
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")");
```

I find that when the axis is rendered in a bar chart with 5 bars, it tacks on numbers at the end. So I get:

`b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,0,1,2,3,4.`

Also the bars are not aligned to the ticks.

How do I make the axis behave so that I get `b1,b2,b3,b4,b5` under the 5 bars ?

Here's the entire function:

```
  function barchart_2d_array(width, height, barwidth, data, target_div){


    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        w = width + margin.left + margin.right,
        h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;



    var dataset = data;

    values_arr=[];

    for(var o in dataset){
        values_arr.push(dataset[o]);
    }

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .rangeBands([0, width], .1);



    var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0,d3.max(values_arr)])
                    .range([height,0]);



    var svg = d3.select(target_div)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("style","border : 1px solid black")
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    x.domain(["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]);

    window.x=x;
    window.width=width;

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(values_arr)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x",function(d,i){
            return x(i);
        })
        .attr("y",function(d,i){
            return y(d);
        })
        .attr("width",barwidth)
        .attr("height",function(d,i){
            return height - y(d);
        });

    var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(y)
                      .orient("left")
                      .ticks(5);

    var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(x)
                      .orient("bottom");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(yaxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(xaxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")");

};
```

This is how I call it:

```
<div id="bar_chart">

</div>
<script>
    var dataset = { "b1":100, "b2":200, "b3":300, "b4":400, "b5":500 };

    a = barchart_2d_array(400,200, 5,dataset,"#bar_chart");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3's ordinal scales will implicitly add values into the domain if they haven't been seen before.  Your code is passing in the additional values you're seeing in this function:

```
.attr("x",function(d,i){
    return x(i);
})
```

`i` is the index of the node in the selection starting at 0.

You should take another look at the data set you're binding because I don't think it's doing what you want.  You turn the data object into an array but in the process you're dropping the property names.  Your array just contains the values (`[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]`), not the bar names that the `x` scale is expecting.

You probably want your array to look more like `[{name: b1, value: 100}, {name: b2, value: 200}...]` and then you can scale the data for `x` and `y` like this:

```
.attr("x",function(d) {
    return x(d.name);
})
.attr("y",function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
})
```

Once you get the shape of the bound data right everything else should fall into place.

Comment: I updated the question with the entire code. I was trying to use jsfiddle but failed miserably.

Comment: I modified the answer to something more complete based on the code you posted.

Comment: Hi Scott, that was the problem. I rearranged my dataset, and now everything looks good. Thanks!